# .Net Core 2 subject

Tags: c#, events, asp.net-core, subject

Is it possible that call event by name in net core 2 ( without specifying a particular class or function ) and everywhere waiting for this event, codes run.
Like subject in typescript.

Comment: if its not possible, you can say that !

Comment: Typescript doesn't have subjects. Are you confusing typescript with the JavaScript library RxJS?

Comment: yes you right. i searching now for rx.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language does not allow to do so.

However, if you are looking for something that resembles subjects, you can use [Rx.NET](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) because subjects are not typescript objects, but are imported from rxjs.

Rx.NET, rxjs are equivalent implementation of the RX framework in their respective languages.

Comment: RX/ReactiveExtensions was a microsoft research project and RX.NET is its first implementation. All others are ports ;)

Comment: I didn't know it was the other way around. I edit the answer. Thank you!